# SELECT * и SELECT column возвращает строки в разном порядке

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос №1:

```
WITH cte1 AS
  (SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS rn
   FROM table)
SELECT column0
FROM cte1
WHERE rn = 1022;
```

есть запрос №2:

```
WITH cte1 AS
  (SELECT column0,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1) AS rn
   FROM table)
SELECT column0
FROM cte1
WHERE rn = 1022;
```

PostgreSQL, в column0 нет NULL-ов, значения уникальны.

Но, почему то, при `SELECT *` и `SELECT column0` в итоге я получаю разные значения на rn 1022 (не только на 1022, это просто для примера). Сортировка в cte1 одна и та же, ничего не меняется, кроме количества колонок. Эта какая-то особенность SQL или с чем может быть связано?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это особенность SQL. **Если у вас явно не указана сортировка, то база данных может вернуть строки в любом порядке.** Как ей захочется.
И это может зависить не только от звездочки в запросе, но и просто от времени когда делается запрос.

Хотите избежать неоднозначности - указывайте сортировку в явном виде.

Comment: *"Если у вас явно не указана сортировка, то база данных может вернуть строки в любом порядке"* - это прям болдом писать надо. +1

Comment: **Всё, что не описано явно, может быть как угодно.**

Comment: То что тут написано правда, но проблема совсем не в этом. См. мой ответ.

Comment: Вот если бы Вы сказали ** в column1 нет NULL-ов, значения уникальны** - это действительно был бы вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что сортировка по `column1` в вашем случае неоднозначна т.е. в этом поле есть дубликаты и отсортировать по `column1` можно разными способами, что БД и делает при разных запросах.

Вот пример:

```
column0 | column1
--------+---------
  A     |      1
  B     |      1
```

Если выполнить запрос из CTE, до любой порядок строк будет правильным и если вы будете выбирать, скажем, `rn=1` то вы можете получить в результате и `A` и `B`.

Чтоб этого избежать нужно задавать сортировку по полям, которые однозначно задают порядок. Обычно достаточно включить последним (т.е. самым низкоприоритетным) полем в сортировке уникальное поле (например, первичный ключ), что-то вроде такого:

```
SELECT column0,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1, id) AS rn
FROM table
```

В этом случае порядок всегда будет определен однозначно, т.к. для записей с одинаковыми значениями `column1` сортировка будет происходить по полю `id`.